# A continuous macro to clear adjacent cells Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a continuous macro that would check for an error in a column, and if there is, would clear the contents in an adjacent cell. The Column with the error has a formula that would fill in data depending on what value is in the adjacent cell. So I want program to clear away the value of the adjacent cell if an invalid value was inputted. This is what I have so far, but I am unsure how to specify an adjacent cell to the associated error. I put in the X to indicate a varied row value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheet(1)
        If Target.Column = 2 Then
            If IsError(Target.Value) Then
               *- Range("AX").ClearContents -*
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Offset(0,1)` gets you to one cell to the right -- if that is what you mean by the word "adjacent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you have is that you are using the `Worksheet_Change` event and identifying the **formula cell** as the target. This will *never* work as changes in formula results do not get triggered by the `Worksheet_Change` event. (You can process these with the `Worksheet_Calculate` event though - but that is not what you need here). The cell actually be changed needs to be evaluated.

What would probably serve you better is [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9) set up on the input cells to ensure the correct input is provided. In this way, no VBA is necessary. However, if that doesn't work, the code below will work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'worksheet_change will always work on the current worksheet, only identify _
another worksheet if you want to act on a range in a different sheet

'-> 3 assumes the input column is C (based on your description)
If Target.Column = 3 And IsError(Target.Offset(,-1)) And Target.Rows.Count = 1 and Target.Columns = 1 Then 

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(,-1).ClearContents
    'Msgbox "Enter a valid value." ' possible warning message
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Side note, is there a way to check for changes in formula results?

Comment: What I need is to clear the contents of the input, but if I do that the change events will continue to trigger and cause an infinite loop.

Comment: see my edit @KevinLe - I forgot one **very important** step in my original answer. I also made it work for one only one cell change at a time. You can modify if you need to test against ranges.